# Grails: Unable to generate views

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class, grails-2.3

This is a very basic thing and I have no idea why am not able to do this. I am using Grails 2.3.5

I have a domain class com.trail.AuditTrail and I want it scaffolded views. So, here are the steps I followed:

- ran `grails create-controller com.trail.AuditTrail`, this returned a message saying it generated:

  > grails-app/controller/trail/AuditTrailController
  >
  > grails-app/views/auditTrail (just the folder!)

  It also created AuditTrailControllerSpec.groovy.
- Then I added the line `static scaffold = true` in the Controller.
- Then ran `generate-views` to create the views, but nothing got created !

IMPORTANT: In fact grails says that there is no command called as generate-views. When I did `grails help` it didn't list generate-views. So, I thought may be 2.3.5 doesn't have the command and tried generate-all. This too failed. To my surprise, grails help didn't show up generate-all too !

Then I found this bug: https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10530. So, I tried clean, refresh-dependencies, compile and then generate-all. But still the same problem.

I thought my local grails setup is messed up. So, asked my colleague. He too sees the same problems.

My problem is I am not able to create the default template GSPs out of the domain.

Comment: Do you have scaffolding plugin installed ?

Comment: Thanks a ton emilan ! I didn't even know that Grails removed the scaffolding and created a plugin out of it since 2.3. Actually, we were on 2.2.1 earlier and later upgraded to 2.3.5. So, this got missed and we never realized this until now. Thank you again. Place your comment as an answer and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scaffolding functionality was extracted from Grails core in 2.3, so you need to install `scaffolding` plugin for `Grails 2.3.5` to be able to use `generate-all`, `generate-views` `GANT` scripts.

P.S. I suggest you to switch to Grails 2.3.6 or 2.3.7. For more details take a look at this article http://www.gopivotal.com/security/cve-2014-0053

Answer (score 1):

for that right click on action then click on generate view